# Как выровнять QWidget ровно по середине?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

При выполнении следующего кода:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("app")
window.resize(300, 100)
window.move(window.width() * -2, 0)
window.show()

desktop = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop()

x = (desktop.width() - window.frameSize().width()) // 2
y = (desktop.height() - window.frameSize().height()) // 2

window.move(x, y)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

который должен выравнивать окно по середине, происходит следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

...

app = QApplication([])

window = QWidget()

rect = window.frameGeometry()
center = app.desktop().availableGeometry().center()
rect.moveCenter(center)
window.move(rect.topLeft())

window.show()

app.exec()
```

Вариант через ручной подсчет:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

app = QApplication([])

window = QWidget()
window.resize(300, 100)
window.show()

desktop = app.desktop()
x = (desktop.availableGeometry().width() - window.width()) // 2
y = (desktop.availableGeometry().height() - window.height()) // 2

window.move(x, y)

app.exec()
```

Comment: Почему мой код работает неправильно?

Comment: @Lcashe, есть различия в результате. Например, у меня: `print(desktop.frameSize()) # PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(3200, 1080)`, `print(desktop.availableGeometry()) # PyQt5.QtCore.QRect(63, 0, 1857, 1080)``. 3200 взялось, думаю, потому что у меня два монитора, а 63 это скорее всего ширина панели задач (у меня она вертикальная и слева)

Comment: Кст, если решать вашим алгоритмом через вычитание и деление, то можно так: https://github.com/gil9red/BatchImageConverter/blob/29d4b701f1cf38664739d0d220be3831d733c00b/UBatchImageConverter/UBatchImageConverter.cpp#L16 (мой старый код на с++)

Comment: т.е. ```size.width()``` вместо ```desktop.width()```?

Comment: Не, использовать `desktop.availableGeometry().width()` и `desktop.availableGeometry().height()`. Добавил пример